# La función get_headers me devuelve bool(false)

Tags: php

Necesito ayuda.
Estoy usando un código donde utilizo el `get_headers($image)`
el problema que me devuelve `bool(false)`

> En vez de: array(11) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(15) " http=""
>   1.0="" 200="" ok"="" [1]="">....

En `http://localhost` me anda bien pero en una pagina `http://xxxxxxx` no.
¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir porque `get_headers` puede deshabilitarse en el servidor. Por eso te funcionaría en local pero no cuando lo pongas online. Prueba a poner `error_reporting(E_ALL);` para ver todos los errores y quizás obtengas alguna pista

Comment: Exacto @alvaro-montoro, estaba deshabilitado en el servidor.
Termine resolviendo mi problema con curl.
Gracias por tu repuesta

Comment: Genial. Puedo poner el comentario como respuesta, pero casi mejor si respondes a tu propia pregunta con los pasos que seguiste para habilitarlo en el servidor. Puede ser de utilidad para otros usuarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque `get_headers` está deshabilitado en el servidor. Por eso te funcionaría en local pero no cuando lo pongas online (en local estará habilitado). Si activas los errores y warnings en el servidor (con `error_reporting(E_ALL)`) verás un mensaje como éste:

> Warning: get_headers() has been disabled for security reasons

Si quieres que `get_headers()` funcione en el servidor, tienes que activarlo. Para ello:

- Asegúrate de que tienes la versión correcta en el servidor (`get_headers` funciona con PHP5 y PHP7).
- En el fichero php.ini, asegúrate que `allow_url_fopen` tiene el valor `On`:

  ```
  allow_url_fopen = On
  ```

Si no puedes cambiar la configuración del servidor, o tu servidor no cumple las condiciones de versión, podrías usar cURL (como parece que hiciste e indicas en los [comentarios de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62357/la-funci%C3%B3n-get-headers-me-devuelve-boolfalse#comment114966_62357)).